# Display checkout success page print order in pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, print

My checkout success page print order displays in html. When i print it using a webkit browser the table view is distorted. I think the best way to overcome this issue is to display the print order as PDF instead of html. How can i achieve this in magento?

The issue images available below

Normal view : http://postimg.org/image/xg4drghpz/

Print view : http://postimg.org/image/izh4cvs8n/

Comment: You could use sth like fpdf and build your own .pdf invoice

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm trying it using the pdfjs plugin. I'll post an answer once i succeed with it

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses different template for print view.
You may check differences. It is very easy.
Go to `/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout` and look in **sales.xml**

Try to compare sales_order_view and sales_order_print sections. For invoices, shipments, creditmemos it will be similar.

Comment: Sorry i don't see how this will help me to display print order view in pdf instead of html.

Comment: In this case you can create your own mini extension you should to create block and template which will output order data (or you can use current block "sales/order_print" which uses template "sales/order/print.phtml")
In your controller you should to create

public function exportPdfAction(){
    $fileName = 'order.pdf';        
    $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your_custom_block')->getPdfFile();
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
}

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I actually went ahead and created a pdf using the jspdf plugin. Hope this answer will help someone else.